# Retrieve rows for time interval but also previous row of each - how to?

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

```
Id  FKId  Amount1   Amount2 Date
-----------------------------------------------------
1   1     100,0000  33,0000 2018-01-18 19:57:39.403
2   2      50,0000  10,0000 2018-01-19 19:57:57.097
3   1     130,0000  40,0000 2018-01-20 19:58:13.660
5   2      44,0000   2,0000 2018-01-21 11:11:00.000
```

How to get rows from 3 - 5 (all that have dates 2018-01-21 or 2018-01-21) but also their previous row regarding FKId (1 and 2)?

Thank you

Comment: and what did you try so far?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? MySQL , SQL Server , Oracle ???

Comment: is it sql-server, MySQL, oracle ? also please add an expected output for the example

Comment: *all that have dates 2018-01-21 or 2018-01-21* both are **same** dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most databases, you can use the ANSI standard `lead()` function:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lead(date) over (partition by fkid order by date) as next_date
      from t
     ) t
where date in ('2018-01-20', '2018-01-21') or
      next_date in ('2018-01-20', '2018-01-21');
```

Alternatively, if you just want all records where the date is bigger than some date *and the previous record*, this logic also works:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date >= (select max(t2.date)
                 from t t2
                 where t2.fkid = t.fkid and t2.date < '2018-01-20'
                );
```